# Animation software for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, animation, 3d

Which free applications can I use to create 3D animations on Ubuntu/Linux ? I'm sure that my computer's hardware is good enough to run any software.

Answer (score 0):

Blender is the best 3D modeling application for free.

http://www.blender.org/

Also available in Ubuntu software center

Answer (score 0):

My vote is for [Blender](http://www.blender.org/about/)

Here is some text from their site:

> Blender is a free and open source 3D animation suite. It supports the entirety of the 3D pipeline—modeling, rigging, animation, simulation, rendering, compositing and motion tracking, even video editing and game creation.

To give you an example of the kind of results people have obtained using Blender, here is an example of movie made with it: [Short Film Sintel 3D Movie : HD Blender Video Animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LSHLg4hEVZ8)